# use setattribute to change font color (in chat)

Tags: html, setattribute

I want to change the chat window fontcolor/fontsize of the page [younow](http://www.younow.com/). I'm able to change the font size, but I am not able to change the font color.
How can I change the chat window font color?[image] This is what I'm using:

```
document.getElementById("chatcomments").setAttribute('style','font-size:36px; color:red !important;');
```

Comment: You should `cssText` for that ... `document.getElementById("chatcomments").style.cssText = 'font-size: 36px; color: red;'`

Comment: `chatcomments` is not the immediate element for the text, further down is a span, so what if you try this `document.querySelector(".chatcomments span").style.cssText = 'font-size: 36px; color: red;'`

Answer (score 0):

I visited the link and solve your problem. This css code can solve the problem. No javascript is needed.

```css
.comment-content{
     font-size: 20px;
 }
 .comment-content a,
 .comment-content span,
 .comment-content i{
     color: red !important

 }
```